# Linked list issue

Tags: c, linked-list

Iḿ trying to build an usual linked list, and i need to implement 3 functions, new, list and remove. new to add a new node; list to lisk all nodes by priority and by order of creation date; remove to remove one node. I think my problem is the removing of the first node of the list.. Help me pls :)

Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "SO01.h"
#define SIZE 5

void main(void){
  int i;
  list_t* array;
  array=(list_t*) malloc(sizeof(list_t)*(SIZE+1));
  for(i=0; i<=SIZE; i++)
    array[i].first=NULL;
  addNewTask(array, 3, 32);
  addNewTask(array, 4, 33);
  addNewTask(array, 4, 34);
  addNewTask(array, 5, 35);
  addNewTask(array, 5, 36);
  addNewTask(array, 5, 37);

  listTasks(array, 4);
  removeTask(array, 35);
  listTasks(array, 4);
}

void addNewTask(list_t* array1, int prioridade, int id){
  lst_iitem_t* task;
  task=(lst_iitem_t*) malloc(sizeof(lst_iitem_t));
  task->next=NULL;
  task->value=id;
  if(array1[prioridade].first==NULL)
    array1[prioridade].first=task;
  else{ 
    lst_iitem_t* aux;
    aux=array1[prioridade].first;
    while(aux->next != NULL)
      aux = aux->next; 
    aux->next=task;
  }
}

void listTasks(list_t* array1, int prioridade){
  int i;
  for(i=5; i>=prioridade; i--)
    printListFromBack(array1[i].first, i);
}

void printListFromBack(lst_iitem_t * root, int prioridade)
{
  if(!root)
    return;
  else
    if(root->next)
      printListFromBack(root->next, prioridade);
  printf("Prioridade = %d || Id = %d\n", prioridade, root->value);
}

void removeTask(list_t* array1, int id){
  int i;
  lst_iitem_t* curr=NULL, *prev=NULL;
  for(i=0; i<=5; i++){
    curr=array1[i].first;
    for(curr; curr != NULL; prev=curr, curr=curr->next){
      if(curr->value == id){
    if(prev==NULL){
      curr=curr->next;
      }else{
      prev->next=curr->next;
    }
    free(curr);
    return;
      }
    }
  }
  printf("TAREFA INEXISTENTE\n");
}
```

Output:

```
Prioridade = 5 || Id = 37
Prioridade = 5 || Id = 36
Prioridade = 5 || Id = 35
Prioridade = 4 || Id = 34
Prioridade = 4 || Id = 33
Prioridade = 5 || Id = 37
Prioridade = 5 || Id = 36
Prioridade = 5 || Id = 0       <----- why 0 appears?
Prioridade = 4 || Id = 37      <----- Repeating and wrong priority
Prioridade = 4 || Id = 36      <----- Same here
Prioridade = 4 || Id = 34
Prioridade = 4 || Id = 33
```

Thanks for help ;)

Comment: How about debugging your code a bit? Going through it step by step, trying to understand what is actually happening... if it wouldn't help you to solve the problem completely, at least it would help you narrow it down, locate the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that the problem was in the way you deleted the first item from a list.  Here's working code with a minor fix in `removeTask()` that sets `array1[i].first = curr->next;` rather than `curr = curr->next;`.  It also has a `freeTask()` function to release data, and uses `assert()` in a few places to validate that things work as expected.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct list_t list_t;
typedef struct lst_iitem_t lst_iitem_t;

struct list_t
{
    lst_iitem_t *first;
};

struct lst_iitem_t
{
    lst_iitem_t *next;
    int value;
};

void addNewTask(list_t *array1, int prioridade, int id);
void removeTask(list_t *array1, int id);
void listTasks(list_t *array1, int prioridade);
void printListFromBack(lst_iitem_t *root, int prioridade);
void freeTasks(list_t *array1);

#define SIZE 5

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    list_t *array;
    array = (list_t *) malloc(sizeof(list_t)*(SIZE+1));
    for (i = 0; i <= SIZE; i++)
        array[i].first = NULL;
    addNewTask(array, 4, 33);
    addNewTask(array, 3, 32);
    addNewTask(array, 4, 34);
    addNewTask(array, 5, 35);
    addNewTask(array, 5, 36);
    addNewTask(array, 5, 37);

    printf("Before:\n");
    listTasks(array, 4);
    removeTask(array, 35);
    printf("After:\n");
    listTasks(array, 4);
    freeTasks(array);
    return 0;
}

void addNewTask(list_t *array1, int prioridade, int id)
{
    lst_iitem_t *task;
    assert(prioridade >= 0 && prioridade <= SIZE);
    task = (lst_iitem_t *) malloc(sizeof(lst_iitem_t));
    task->next = NULL;
    task->value = id;
    if (array1[prioridade].first == NULL)
        array1[prioridade].first = task;
    else
    {
        lst_iitem_t *aux;
        aux = array1[prioridade].first;
        while (aux->next != NULL)
            aux = aux->next;
        aux->next = task;
    }
}

void listTasks(list_t *array1, int prioridade)
{
    int i;
    assert(prioridade >= 0 && prioridade <= SIZE);
    for (i = SIZE; i >= prioridade; i--)
        printListFromBack(array1[i].first, i);
}

void printListFromBack(lst_iitem_t *root, int prioridade)
{
    if (!root)
        return;
    else if (root->next)
        printListFromBack(root->next, prioridade);
    printf("Prioridade = %d || Id = %d\n", prioridade, root->value);
}

void removeTask(list_t *array1, int id)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= SIZE; i++)
    {
        lst_iitem_t *curr;
        lst_iitem_t *prev = NULL;
        for (curr = array1[i].first; curr != NULL; prev = curr, curr = curr->next)
        {
            if (curr->value == id)
            {
                if (prev == NULL)
                {
                    assert(curr == array1[i].first);
                    array1[i].first = curr->next;
                }
                else
                    prev->next = curr->next;
                free(curr);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("TAREFA INEXISTENTE\n");
}

void freeTasks(list_t *array1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= SIZE; i++)
    {
        lst_iitem_t *curr = array1[i].first;
        while (curr != NULL)
        {
            lst_iitem_t *next = curr->next;
            free(curr);
            curr = next;
        }
    }
    free(array1);
}
```

Sample output:

```
Before:
Prioridade = 5 || Id = 37
Prioridade = 5 || Id = 36
Prioridade = 5 || Id = 35
Prioridade = 4 || Id = 34
Prioridade = 4 || Id = 33
After:
Prioridade = 5 || Id = 37
Prioridade = 5 || Id = 36
Prioridade = 4 || Id = 34
Prioridade = 4 || Id = 33
```

I ran a few variants and extra tests and I'm reasonably sure it is clean.  I've not run it under `valgrind`, but I was using a debugging malloc that would spot grotesque abuses in the function calls (double frees, freeing unallocated, etc).